# C: using realloc() in seperate function doesn't change array size

Tags: c

I feel as though this shouldn't be such a hard problem and I've tried everything that I've found on similar questions to no avail, so I thought I'd give it a try to ask myself. My code (simplified) is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void setArraySize(int** arr) {
    int arrSize;
    printf("\nEnter array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &arrSize);
    int* tmp = realloc(*arr, arrSize);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        return;
    }
    *arr = tmp;
}

void auswahl() {
    int* arr = NULL;
    setArraySize(&arr);
    free(arr);
}

int main() {
    auswahl();
    return 0;
}
```

When debugging I noticed that my array only contains the integer -842150451. I am using Microsoft Visual Studios 2019 Community. Additionally, even when trying the most basic and safest functions, I attain the same result. Could the problem then have to do with Visual Studios?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void increase(int** data)
{
    int* tmp = realloc(*data, 20);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        return;
    }
    *data = tmp;
}

int main() {
    int* arr = NULL;
    increase(&arr);
    printf("%d", sizeof(arr));
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: *my array only contains the integer -842150451* - what should it contain?

Comment: If you use `calloc` it will contain `0`.

Comment: Everything in your code is working as expected. `realloc` doesn't put anything into the array. It just reserves memory for the array. If you want something in the array, you need to put something in the array.

Comment: in 'c' there is absolutely no way to get the size of an array allocated dynamically. So, do not try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your second code a little bit (added printf's), it will help you understand what is happening

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void increase(int** data)
{
    printf ("in increase|*data|%p|\n", *data);
    int* tmp = realloc(*data, 20);
    printf ("in increase|*data after realloc|%p|\n", *data);
    printf ("in increase|tmp after realloc|%p|\n", tmp);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        return;
    }
    *data = tmp;
    printf ("in increase|*data after assign|%p|\n", *data);
}

int main() {
    int* arr = NULL;
    printf ("in main|arr|%p|\n", arr);
    printf ("in main|arr size|%d|\n", sizeof(arr));
    increase(&arr);
    printf ("in main|arr after increase|%p|\n", arr);
    printf ("in main|arr size after increase|%d|\n", sizeof(arr));
    return 0;
}
```

this will output this :

```
in main|arr|(nil)|                                                                                                            
in main|arr size|8|                                                                                                           
in increase|*data|(nil)|                                                                                                      
in increase|*data after realloc|(nil)|                                                                                        
in increase|tmp after realloc|0x2441010|                                                                                      
in increase|*data after assign|0x2441010|                                                                                     
in main|arr after increase|0x2441010|                                                                                         
in main|arr size after increase|8|
```

So basically the size of `arr` doesn't change because it's not an array, it's a pointer to an int, the size here is 8 because it's a 64bits machine, and memory adresses for 64bits need 8 Bytes to be stored, and this is what `sizeof()` returns the size in bytes of the type you gave it ( `int* arr` a pointer to an int )

for the other values you can see that you have effectively allocated memory in the heap at address `0x2441010` so your QUOTE"array"QUOTE (it's not an array), starts at this address and have enough space for 20(BYTES) if you wanted 20 integers you should have used `realloc(..., 20* sizeof(int))` because these alloc functions use bytes as their  unit.

hope this helps you somehow.